# MYSQL return all fields based on multiple conditions AND distinct on single column but

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a event_table as below.

```
city    country event       date
london  UK      Soccer      8/20/2010
toronto CA      Basketball  8/12/2011
newyork US      Basketball  8/21/2012
LA      US      Basketball  8/30/2013
.....
```

[image: event_table]

I need to get all fields with these conditions:

1. 30 entries only
2. event = "Baseketball"
3. order by date
4. Distinct Country "US".

I tried below:

```
select distinct on country * 
from event_table
 where event="Basketball" 
 order by   date Dec limit 20;
```

and below:

```
select * 
from event_table 
where event="Basketball" 
order by    date Dec limit 20 
group by country;
```

But none working. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: what does distinct countries mean? only one country?

Comment: yes, I only want to get back to one country each time.

Comment: Your last SQL statement looks ok for me, except that the limit should be at the end of the statement as I remeber. What's not ok with the result?

Comment: which mysql version ?

Comment: select *  from event_table  where event="Basketball" group by `country` order by `date` desc limit 20;

Comment: I do find put "group by" before the "order by" does not sort date correctly. So it does not solve the issue yet!

Answer (score 0):

Fro only one country it is enough to make

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_table 
WHERE event="Basketball" 
AND country = 'US'
ORDER BY   `date` DESC
LIMIT 30
```

If you want more counties use

```
SELECT
city, country, event, `date`
FROM
    (SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY county ORDER BY `date` DESC)  rn
    FROM event_table 
    WHERE event="Basketball") t1
WHERE rn <= 30
```

You can then select the countrie you like

Comment: Thanks nbk. But I can't put country as "US" as this is another variable, meaning this time I want to get from only US but next time could be only CA. Anyway to make it work?

Comment: usually you have a language like python,c c++ c# asp nez vb net ruby  or php or a stored procedure where you can use variables.

Comment: select * from event_table where event="Basketball" group by country order by date desc limit 20; – Jens 53 mins ago      This worked!

Comment: group by works only if full_GROUP_By is disabled and it will not give you the answer you are looking for as limit will show actually only 20 values and the query will show 20 countries, please try the coments and answers

Comment: Thanks nbk. I want to get 20 values but display each county only once for each query. What do you mean by full-Group-By is disabled?                  I do find put "group by" before the "order by" does not sort date correctly. So it does not solve the issue yet!

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by